# Magento 2 Get product attributeId in foreach loop

Tags: product, product-attribute, magento2.2.2, attribute-options

I have a collection of product I am looping and displaying for E.G

```
...    
$product->getName()
...
$product->getProductUrl()
...
```

Now Also I am getting it some option like attributeText foreach product E.G

```
$product->getAttributeText('color') // this gives me red,green,blue so on...
```

Now My question is how do I get ID:

> $product->getAttributeId('color')

I know that in `\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product` there is a function like so:

```
/**
 * Get attribute text by its code
 *
 * @param string $attributeCode Code of the attribute
 * @return string
 */
public function getAttributeText($attributeCode)
{
    return $this->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeCode)->getSource()->getOptionText(
        $this->getData($attributeCode)
    );
}
```

I could and I did test and it worked so potentially I could do a function :

```
 public function getAttributeId($attributeCode)
{
    return $this->getResource()->getAttribute($attributeCode)->getSource()->getOptionId(
        $this->getData($attributeCode)
    );
}
```

That works but how to implement this outside of vendor folder or if there is another way to get the id even better please share.

Thanks.

Comment: Please check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to get custom and default attribute option data. For example:

```
<?php

$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$atrributesRepository  = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Attribute\Repository');
$selectOptions = $atrributesRepository->get('AttributeCode')->getOptions();
foreach ($selectOptions as $selectOption) {
    print_r($selectOption->getData());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add to the constructor of your class an instance of `\Magento\Eav\Model\Config` like this:

```
protected $eavConfig;
public function __construct(
    ...
    \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
    ...
){
    ...
    $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
    ...
}
```

then you can use that in your class

```
$attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'attribute_code_here');
$options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
$values = [];
foreach ($options as $OptionData) { 
        $values[] = $OptionData->getId();
}
    return $values;
```

**Don't use Object Manager Directly.**